# Clojure: set atom's value to true

Tags: clojure

I want to change the atom, which only holds one boolean to true.
I came up with this workaround, is there something I'm missing?

```clj
(defn always-true [x]
  "Used to change atom value"
  true
  )

(def x (atom false)) 
(swap! x always-true)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there's the `reset!` function for atoms,  for this exact usecase:

```
(reset! x false)
```